# Python script will not move a downloaded file when run as CRON

Tags: python, centos7

I have a Python script, which connects to a data feed in the early hours of each morning, downloads a JSON data file, then moves it from where it saved it to a dedicated folder.

When the script is run from the command line on the Linux Centos7 server, all works perfectly.  When run through Cron (either on schedule or a run now through the Plesk Cron screen) it errors out.  Having commented out the os.rename(startfile, sendfile) line the script runs perfectly in Cron.

I thought it was todo with permissions, but if I get the same script to open a text file in the eventual destination directory that I am trying to move the datafile to, write 'JSON file downloaded ok' and close the file - that runs perfectly under CRON, so I dont think it can be permissions.

I have run os.path.isfile(StartFile) on the datafile after downloaded (and got TRUE) and run os.path.isdir(EndFile) and got TRUE, so I know the paths are correct.  I have replaced os.rename with os.replace and the same thing happens.

When the script downloads it, it goes into the /root/ folder, as CRON runs as root. When the script exits with an error, the file is there and visible in /root/ and I can manually do mv file.gz to /path/to/folder/file.gz and it moves fine.

Just CRON is having some issue with the Python file movement commands - can anyone offer any advice, I just dont know where to check next!

Comment: Are you using relative or absolute paths to specify the file to move? Cron uses a different current working directory, which changes relative paths.

Comment: try explicitly setting you cwd with os.chdir(path).

Comment: @NickODell I have tried both, and both failed.  As I can see the files are downloaded to /root/ when the job fails, I have specified /root/filename.gz as the start file - but while os.path.isfile reports true, so its obviously found it, it still fails.

Comment: Are `/root` and `/path/to/folder` in the same filesystem? `os.rename` is not equivalent to `mv`. Check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename). Try `shutil.move` instead.

Comment: @kpie Ah well done that man, why did I not think of that.  Setting the destination Path as the CWD avoids the need for the move and the file just downloads in the correct folder to start with!  Still not sure why the move didn't work, but thank you you've sorted me out! Much appreciated.

Comment: @nickie Yes both on the save server and same file system.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kpie in the above comments, the answer (although I suppose it is a workaround rather than a solution) was to change the working directory with os.chdir(path) before downloading the file.

That way the file downloads into the folder I need it in, rather than downloading and then moving it.